# In VB6, how to get previously selected row in mshflexgrid?

Tags: vb6, grid, row, mshflexgrid

When a user wants to change the selected row in a grid, the program asks him if he would like to continue. If **No**, the selected row must not change. The problem is, whether the user clicked **Yes** or **No**, the selected row changes to the row the user has clicked. I don't know if I can use the **Validate** function but please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The MSFlexGrid events alone don't seem to give this ability. You could keep track of the previous row in a module variable. When the user goes to a new row you can prompt whether they want to change rows. If they click No you can set the row back to what it was, otherwise store the row you are now in.

Something like this

```
Private previousRow As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    previousRow = MSFlexGrid1.Row
End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_RowColChange()
    If previousRow <> MSFlexGrid1.Row Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to change rows?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            MSFlexGrid1.Row = previousRow
        Else
            previousRow = MSFlexGrid1.Row
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```